# Change "Total" text when specific products in cart on WooCommerce cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I want the text "Total" on WooCommerce cart and checkout page (see attached image) to be changed if there is a specific product ID in cart.

[image]

---

I tried achieving this in javascript but it will just apply to all:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#your_my_order_element_id').html('Your New string');
//$('.your_my_order_element_class').html('Your New string');
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Can someone push me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the total text on the cart and checkout page, you could edit the template file. As can be found in [templates/cart/cart-totals.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/cart/cart-totals.php)

This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.`

So replace (Line 97 - 100 - @version 2.3.6)

```php
<tr class="order-total">
    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
</tr>
```

With

```php
<tr class="order-total">
    <?php
    // The targeted product ids, multiple product IDs can be entered, separated by a comma
    $targeted_ids = array( 30, 815 );
    
    // Flag, false by default
    $flag = false;
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
            $flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        ?>
        <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Authorize', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Authorize', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

---

---

OR instead of overwriting the template file, use [gettext()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) filter.

Code goes in `functions.php` file of the active child theme (or active theme)

```php
function filter_gettext( $translated, $original_text, $domain ) {
    // Is admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $translated;
    
    // No match
    if ( $original_text != 'Total' ) return $translated;
    
    // The targeted product ids, multiple product IDs can be entered, separated by a comma
    $targeted_ids = array( 30, 815 );
    
    // Flag, false by default
    $flag = false;
    
    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        $translated =  __( 'Authorize', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'filter_gettext', 10, 3 );
```